# Declaring a global Claim by Identity User

Tags: c#, globalization, superclass

Hi everyone i need help about using global claims using identity security in c#, I can get the values of the cllaims from the user that is authenticated using the following code:

```
namespace Webapplicationsecurity2
{
    public partial class VistaCandidato : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
            //IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;
            var claimRol = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role);
            var claimCve = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName);
            String Cveusuario = claimCve.Value.ToString();




  *but the problem is that i need to make these vars as global in order to use them in other methods but if i put the above code outside of the pageload the system says i can not use type "var" as global, so i tried with the following way:*


namespace Webapplicationsecurity2
{
    public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        dbDataContext db;
       // public const string claimRol;

        public static Claim CveUsuario = ((ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User).FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName.ToString());
        int idusuario = Convert.ToInt32(CveUsuario.Value);

        public static Claim Rol = ((ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User).FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Actor);
        int rolusuario = Convert.ToInt32(Rol.Value);
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        db = new dbDataContext();
```

changing type var to Claim and it seems to be ok but when i run the application i get an error

can not convert from type 'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal' to 'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity'.

please anyone can help me how to solve this? thank s in advanced

Comment: Are all of your tags related?

Comment: Why did you tag java and c and then use c# in your question?!

Comment: @litelite I guess OP is considering C# a mixture of C and Java...

Comment: Sorry guys im new in this nad will take more care about the Tags next time

Comment: Cool. Tags are important. They are attracting right (or wrong) people to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution usign a Session var in the page load method:

```
        var claimRol = ((ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User).FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role);
        Session["Rol"] = claimRol.Value.ToString();// this is the global var
```

but is there another way to fix my problem without using a Session var? if i use var session there is not need of using claims, please some one help me.